# sprite kit JSTileMap Scene Size issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am having all sorts of trouble trying to get the scene size right.

I am loading a JSTileMap with the following scene size:

```
SKScene * scene = [GameLevelScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

The tiles appear twice the size (too large).

[image: skview.bounds.size]

If I set the scene size specifically:

```
SKScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1136, 640)];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

[image: CGSizeMake(1136,640)]

The tiles appear in the correct size.  I am using an iPhone 5 for the simulator device. I want to be able to resize the scene for any device not just the iPhone 5. I thought the first method would solve this but it doesn't??  Why is this happening?

Comment: do you present the scene in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I present the scene in: ViewDidAppear. I am not using ViewDidLoad.

Comment: I have tried all three different methods:  viewDidLoad , viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear.  All do the same thing.

Comment: When using skView.bounds.size and checking the scene size it is exactly half the expected size: 568,320 instead of 1136,640

Comment: that's the size in points, all positioning in sk and uikit happens in points to better support the high density retina displays

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "@2x" after your tile set(s). This might fix your issue. This basically scales the image twice as much, (i.e. a 200x200 tileset becomes 100x100)